# How to set alignment center in TextBox in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

How to set align center for an `<asp:TextBox>` control in an ASP.NET Web Application?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add the css styling `text-align: center` to the control.

Ideally you would do this through a css class assigned to the control, but if you must do it directly, here is an example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" style="text-align: center"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

```
<asp:textbox id="textBox1" style="text-align:center"></asp:textbox>
```

Or this:

```
textbox.Style["text-align"] = "center"; //right, left
```

Answer (score 1):

To center align text

```
input[type='text'] { text-align:center;}
```

To center align the textbox in the container that it sits in, apply text-align:center to the container.